# Wordpress Session Variable exist but not working when i access in plugin wp-estore

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

I have assigned an array variable in session for temporary use. Session variable store customer information before checkout using paypal. After checkout I want to store session variable data in database table. Session Variable exist and i can access through template of theme. But When I try to access that session variable in wp-store plugin. It show blank data.

My session variable is

`$_SESSION['userinfo'] = $userinfo;`

In template of theme , I can directly access session variable that give perfect output.

`var_dump($_SESSION['userinfo']);`

Similar way, In plugin it give Blank data

```
$sesData =$_SESSION['userinfo'];

$lname = $sesData['lname'];
$phone = $sesData['phone'];
$addrs = $sesData['addr'];
$lanc = $sesData['lanc'];
$latc = $sesData['latc'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sessions aren't enabled in wordpress by default, so you have to activate php sessions in theme and plugin.

When the user logs out or logs into a different account session should be destroyed.

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id())
        session_start();
}
function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Comment: Oh my! I could have gone done a rabbit hole with this one :) Luckily I found this one early.

THANK YOU

Comment: Just one note: PHP recommends unsetting the $_SESSION arr rather than destroying the session https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Answer (score 0):

Add below action to plugin

```
function register_session()
{
  if( !session_id() )
  {
    session_start();
  }
}

add_action('init', 'register_session');
```

Comment: Should i add it in  Function.php of theme  ?

Comment: by adding above code in function.php , Not working for me